# Internal CSS issue on Email client- Sitecore EmailCampaign 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

Created new email template using score components. Added styles for the classes provided. But email clients are not supporting internal css. 
We want to make it as inline CSS.
Is there any way to convert internal styles to inline styles in sitecore ECM.

If yes which convertor(dll) should I use to convert and which pipeline should I override.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: This is not a programming question. -1

Comment: You can read the html generated by email template but css resources you cannot. This been said if you are using mail with presentation details move all your css as inline style inside layouts and sublayouts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand your issue of having inline styles, but in any case please consider the link below as may prompt you with understanding how to create styled templates in Sitecore ECM:

http://www.craigtaylor.us/2014/04/creating-responsive-email-template-for-sitecore-ecm.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried the same way. but email clients are not taking internal css. Is there any tool to convert internal css to inline styles

Answer (score 0):

Ah-h, I think now I got understanding what your issue is. It comes from the fact that email clients are very conservative and sometimes you need to code you mail message HTML as you did that back 10 years ago.

Likewise you did in the past - support for different browsers (typically IE and others) - now you need to support much wider range of email clients.

Here is the link you will definitely find useful - The Ultimate Guide to CSS (for email clients) - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Hope this helps!